# Expected type 'Union[str, int]' (matched generic type '_VT'), got 'List[Dict[str, str]]' instead

Tags: python, словари, dict

Вылетает такое предупреждение, когда я пытаюсь в словаре создать новое поле и присвоить ему значение в виде списка

Есть некий заполненный словарь и в цикле я делаю следующее:

```
dict_one['new_field'] = list_info (здесь возникает предупреждение)
```

Сам список выглядит примерно так

```
list_info = [{'name': 'jack', 'id': 73457, 'count': '345'}, {'name': 'mike', 'id': 34625, 'count': '6345'}, {'name': 'dave', 'id': 3672345, 'count': '785'}]
```

То есть значениями ключей могут быть как строки, так и числа

Comment: Это все что у вас есть? Судя по описанию, все должно отработать без проблем

Comment: оно отрабатывает, но я не понимаю, почему возникает это предупреждение, и как его исправить

Comment: Скорей всего ваша IDE ругается, надо не в коде python искать решения, а в вашем рабочем окружении. Скорей всего у вас PyCharm

Comment: Если у вас действительно PyCharm, то я не знаток, может вот [это поможет](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-inspection-severities.html) или вот [эта ветка на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48132786/10562663)